# Windows 7: How to boot up in normal mode after improper shut down?

Tags: windows-7

I work in two different locations  and whenever there is a power outage at one of the locations, Windows 7 detects that the system was improperly shutdown. Once the power is up, the PC powers on and Windows 7 enters REPAIR/SAFE mode where only someone physically in front of the PC can control it. (Networking is all disabled in this mode)

Now before it enters REPAIR/SAFE mode, there is an option for a NORMAL boot. But the catch is that REPAIR/SAFE mode is selected by default with a 30 second timer. Once it automatically enters REPAIR/SAFE mode and if nobody is at the other location, I have no way to remote control it anymore. And then I have to drive over to the other location and reboot it and select boot into NORMAL mode.

Where can I change this setting so that Windows 7 always boots into NORMAL mode no matter how many times it is improperly shut down?

Comment: Have you thought about investing in a UPS for the PC at the remote location? If power cuts are frequent it will pay itself back in the time you don't have to spend resetting the machine.

Comment: Tks for the comment. This will only work if the power is out for a brief period but what if the power is out for 1-2 days? I'm stuck with a PC in SAFE mode in a remote location with no one to control it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had a nasty power outage and gruntled's answer did not fully solve my initial concern 2 years ago. Because of an initial misconfiguration, I am now booking an expensive plane trip back to the staff-less server room in the other country just because of a simple boot problem. (no hard feelings)

After doing some more research online and to extend gruntled's answer it seems the correct settings for bcdedit should be:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures <-- Newly added setting

bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

If I don't get any more problems in the future with this setting, I'll keep this as the answer. Hope I saved some lucky person the cost of a plane trip ride back to fix a simple boot problem.

Answer (score 4):

This has been quite the difficult question. There doesn't seem to be much of anything out there. The only viable solution out there seems to be the following.

WARNING: This can damage your system, use at own risk.

First run a command line window as administrator.

Start Menu > All Programs > Accessories > (right-click & "Run as administrator") Command prompt

next run the following commands

```
bcdedit /export C:\BCDbak
```

This will make an export of your Boot Configuration Data Store. You can import it with

```
bcdedit /import C:\BCDbak   
bcdedit /import C:\BCDbak /clean
```

You can now try to disable recoverymode with the following command.

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

This answer may work for you, but I certainly recommend that you invest in a UPS for this sytem.

---

EDIT: You can also display your configuration by running

```
bcdedit /enum
```

and

```
bcdedit /enum /v
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of ignoring all failures, you can ignore shutdown failures only:

```
BCDEdit /set bootstatuspolicy ignoreshutdownfailures
```

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794974(v=winembedded.60).aspx). If you run BitLocker with TPM key protection, be aware that the TPM will detect the BCD change and refuse key release to Windows. Therefore, make sure to re-seal the key before rebooting.

```
Manage-bde c: -protectors -disable
Manage-bde c: -protectors -enable
```