# Windows 7 won't restart with SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have this annoying problem that I just can't seem to fix.

Recently I upgraded my main boot drive to an OCZ Vertex Turbo (60GB) which is an SSD. I've installed Windows 7 64bit. The drive works, and is really quick... blah blah blah.

My problem is when I do a restart, for example click start, then arrow next to shutdown, and restart. The computer will shut down, and do a warm reboot, but it gets stuck where it says loading Windows. Just before the animation starts.

So what I have to do is physically press the reset switch on the computer, then it restarts, firing up a menu which offers to launch Windows Startup Repair, so I select "Start Windows Normally".

After this I boot in normally, but its damn annoying.

Any ideas why this is happening, what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Did you do a clean install of Win 7 to the SSD or clone it from an existing install on a hard drive? What other hardware does your system use (motherboard)? Is the BIOS current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have that issue as well occasionally. For me it's either because I have an external hard drive plugged in via USB or I have my PS3 controller still attached from charging it up.

Now I don't know if either of those apply to you, but you may want to try unplugging some stuff from your USB ports and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: ok, yes I have an external USB device plugged in. let me run some tests with it unplugged, will check it out.

Comment: This seems to have identified the cause. Wonder what can be done to fix this, because I can't unplug my usb hdd, each time I want to reboot.

Comment: That's what I've ended up doing. I unplug it at reboot each time. I dunno if anything can be done... I'd like to think so.

Ultimately, if you leave it run long enough, it will continue to boot into Windows, but we're talking 10 minute boot times here usually for me. It seems to be scanning the hard drive... perhaps something similar to chkdsk... But beyond educated guessings, I've no idea how to stop it.

Comment: thanks for that extra info, so its not frozen, I'll continue investigating.

Comment: My wife's Xp machine used to do this, it was specific to a particular usb device or hub. I don't know if it still does it with 7. but my Laptop and mini with windows 7 will have issues shutting down or booting up sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is happening but you can try this fix:

Follow the instructions from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/152720/windows-7-how-to-boot-up-in-normal-mode-after-improper-shut-down) that I asked and disable Windows Startup Repair so it will just boot into normal mode automatically without any intervention.

The main command you want is:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

Check the [question](https://superuser.com/questions/152720/windows-7-how-to-boot-up-in-normal-mode-after-improper-shut-down) for more info about bcdedit.

Though this might fix your problem, there's still something fundamentally wrong with the your system so try a clean install and see if your boot up problem still occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this might be one way of at least getting around having to wait after hitting reset switch, if it doesn't completely help solve the problem, it does at least make the problem more bearable.